# Is there any way to set the "notify on new answers flag" after submission of question?

Tags: support

I can't find it in the UI of this website and I clicked through before setting it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you view your question the option should be available at the foot of the page between the "Answer Your Question" button and "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged [] or ask your own question."